# Smoothness in von Neumann algebra of measurable functions

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, differential-operators, smoothness

Let $A=L^{\infty}(M)$ be an algebra of essentially bounded measurable function on manifold $M$. Let $D$ be a first order elliptic differential operator acting on some hermitian bundle $S$ over $M$ (think of $D$ as a Dirac or signature operator). How to prove that $f \in A$ is smooth if and only if $t \mapsto e^{itD}fe^{-itD}$ is smooth function?

Comment: Since this map is a homomorphism, its smoothness is equivalent to smoothness at $0$. Derivative at $0$ should be just equal to the action of $D$ on $f$, so by elliptic regularity it is smooth iff $f$ is smooth. I don't know how hard will it be to fill in the details in this particular case, but it seems to me that this is what happens here.